# saveInBackgroundWithBlock not calling the block when it finished working

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to do a simple chat in iOS with Obj-C, and when I press the "send" button, I save the object into Parse and I retrieve all the messages.

When it succeeds, I retrieve all the messages so the last one (mine) should be retrieved as well, but the last one never gets called. What should I do?

This is my code:

```
NSMutableArray *messagesArray;

- (IBAction)sendButtonTapped:(id)sender {

    self.sendButton.enabled = false;
    self.textField.enabled = false;
    PFObject *objectChat = [PFObject objectWithClassName: @"ChatClass"];

    objectChat[@"text"] = self.textField.text;

    [objectChat saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {


        self.sendButton.enabled = true;
        self.textField.enabled = true;

        if (succeeded) {
            self.textField.text = @"";

            [self retrieveMessages];

            NSLog(@"success!");
        } else {
            NSLog(error.description);
        }

    }];


}

-(void) retrieveMessages {
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ChatClass"];
    [query whereKey:@"createdAt" lessThanOrEqualTo:now];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {


        if (error == nil) {

            messagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            for (int i = 0; i < [objects count]; i++) {

                [messagesArray addObject:[[objects objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"text"]];
            }

            runOnMainQueueWithoutDeadlocking(^{

                [self.messageTableView reloadData];

            });

        }

    }];
}

void runOnMainQueueWithoutDeadlocking(void (^block)(void))
{
    if ([NSThread isMainThread])
    {
        block();
    }
    else
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);
    }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance.
Regards.

Comment: Why do you qualify the query as <= now?  To prevent retrieval of messages from the future?  Those, I would think, would be the most interesting messages of all. :-)  Perhaps there's enough of a clock difference with the parse server that the time qualification misses the object just created.  Can you comment out that line?

Comment: Also, there's no need to runOnMainQueueWithoutDeadlocking().  The parse.com completion blocks are run on the main.

Comment: Hi @danh . The "runOnMainQueueWithouthDeadlocking() was because I wasn't sure if it was executing on the main thread, just to prevent error. The original error was the clock difference between my machine and the server. Could you please update this comment as response? Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps there's enough of a clock difference with the parse server that the time qualification misses the object just created. Removing that line should do the trick.